Stability of zero solution to a $\pi$-periodic linear system
Question: Consider the $\pi$-periodic linear system $\dot{x}=A(t)x$, where
\begin{align*}
    A(t)=\begin{pmatrix}
         -1+\frac{3}{2}\cos^2 t & 1-\frac{3}{2}\cos t \sin t\\
            -1-\frac{3}{2}\sin t \cos t & -1+\frac{3}{2}\sin^2 t
    \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
Determine the Lyapunov stability of the zero solution.
My attempt: Let $\rho_{1},\rho_{2}$ be the Floquet multipliers of this system, then
\begin{align*}
    \rho_{1}\rho_{2}=\exp\left( \int_{0}^{\pi} \mathrm{tr}A(t)\,\mathrm{d}t \right)=e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}<1
\end{align*}
However, we can not deduce whether $|\rho|>1$ or not from this inequality. 
Maybe we need to compute $\rho_{1}+\rho_{2}=?$ Let $X(t)$ be the fundamental solution with $X(0)=I$, then $\rho_{1}+\rho_{2}=\mathrm{tr}X(\pi)$. I try to compute the equation that $X(t)$ satisfies:
\begin{align*}
    \dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dt}}\mathrm{tr}X(t)=\mathrm{tr}\dot{X}(t)=\mathrm{tr}(A(t)X(t)).
\end{align*}
It seems hard to get some information about $\mathrm{tr}X(\pi)$.
I would appreciate any answers and comments.

For any $\varepsilon>0$, note that
\begin{align}
x(t)=\varepsilon e^{t/2}\begin{pmatrix}
    \cos t\\
    -\sin t
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
is a solution, and $x(0)=(\varepsilon,0)$ is closed to $(0,0)$. However, $|x(2n\pi)|\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Hence the zero solution is unstable.
